# How to move SSISDB database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssis, system-databases

I have a SQL 2016 instance installed. It has SSISDB for SQL server integration services installed.

Now because it is taking up all the space on our system drive, I need to move its data and log files to a separate disk. To do that I will need to take the db offline.

Is there any repercussions you guys can think of after taking it offline. I have coordinated a time with application guys already.

Comment: Have you set the appropriate logging and retention policies for it?  The default is like 365 days, probably longer than you need to keep around.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer - Sorry -- a dumb question. Where can I find logging and retention policies for SSISDB?

Comment: Integration Services Catalogs -> SSISDB -> Right-click -> Properties

Answer (score 2):

It is more or less the same as moving the data files for a user database, but
you can follow the steps in the documentation [To Move the SSIS Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-ver15#to-move-the-ssis-database) as it has some additional good precautions noted:

> Follow the instructions for moving user databases. For more information, see [Move User Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-user-databases?view=sql-server-ver15).
>
> Ensure that you back up the master key for the SSISDB database and protect the backup file. For more information, see [To Back up the SSIS Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-ver15#backup).

Comment: And always, always, always take a backup before moving a database.  When you offline the database nothing is protecting the files other than some ACLs, which you're probably going to monkey with as part of your move.

Answer (score 0):

There are no big concerns with taking it offline as a part of moving it. I've performed this action a couple of times in the past and encountered no issues.